# Why DECIMAL(0,0) data type declaration creates DECIMAL(10, 0) data type in MySQL? If DECIMAL(0,0) isn't allowed why doesn't it give error instead?

Tags: mysql

Here I create a table as

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    -> column1 DECIMAL(0,0)
    -> );
```

Now,

```
DESCRIBE table1;
```

gives me output -

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column1 | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Thus inspite having declared the data type as `DECIMAL(0,0)`, a field with data type `DECIMAL(10,0)` gets created. Why is it so?

If declaring data type as `DECIMAL(0,0)` is not allowed, why doesn't it show me any error instead?

Comment: Smells like a bug in MySql to me. Using other invalid values, like 100 or -1, give errors as expected.

Comment: `0` could mean "no value given", which in this case would result in the default value `10` as indicated on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: @Progman thank you, please consider providing an answer

Comment: @Alejandro Is there anywhere else in MySQL where we could test using 0 to mean "use the default value"? If so, it could be an undocumented feature, or hard-to-find documentation.